# How do I find out if individual items in CheckedListBox are checked? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I've tried looking in checkedListBox1.Items, but that didn't help. So how do I check if an item in a CheckedListBox is marked? It's in a windows forms application.

Comment: Are you using, `MVC` or `Website`?

Comment: The quality of this question is poor. We have very little context here, which will make it almost impossible to answer. Try providing code samples of what you've tried, what technology you're using, and what you're having problems with.

Comment: Or Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: Sorry for the poor quality question, I just joined the site hoping I could get some help. I'm taking a course in C# right now and I need all the help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of checked items using `CheckedItems` property.

**Example 1:**

```
foreach (var item in this.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
this.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<object>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(item =>
    {
        //do stuff here
        //for example
        MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
    });
```

If you are sure items are `string` for example, you can use `Cast<object>` in above code.

You can get the list of checked indices using `CheckedIndices` property.

**Example:**

```
this.checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Cast<int>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(index =>
    {
        //do stuff here
        //for example
        MessageBox.Show(this.checkedListBox1.Items[index].ToString());
    });
```

Comment: In the two LINQ examples, `.ToList()` is not required.

Comment: @RichardSchneider As I know `ForEach` is a member of `List<T>` does any `ForEach` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` exists?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 foreach (ListItem item in checkedListBox1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                // If the item is selected 

            }
            else
            {
                // Item is not selected, do something else.
            }
        }
```